# Getting OR not user input

Tags: c++

I got a problem with my code. Actually, it works perfect and I'm just looking for a better solution. What I did is something like this (it is only a part of whole, not need to post other part as it is only needed here):

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    int a = 0, int b = 3;
    while(true) {
        a = a * a + b;
        Wait(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to achieve is ability to change variable `b` whenever I want. The best solution I've found so far is using getche() as it doesn't need to push enter every time, but still I have to put something every time. The perfect solution would be like: if user want to change `b`, he puts a new value(just one number needed), if not the loop just goes on and on. Any ideas? I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: If you are using `c++` I would recommend `while(true)` instead of `while(1)` for better reachability.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In original code it is true, I put 1 here cause.. don't know why :P but thanks for it! No idea how to solve this?

Comment: So your program freezes when he is doing the while loop? I think you need to use threads. And you are talking about `getche()` but not using it in your code yet?

Comment: It does the multiply line all the time but effect is freeze, yeah. I didn't use getche() because it is not what I want to have in my code. With getche() I have to put something in with every itteration and want to have it optional.

Comment: @martijnn2008 huh? you're going to need to explain this "better reachability" thing

Comment: readability -_- saw it too late couldnt change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this? I haven't tested this yet.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool loop;
int a = 0, b = 0;
void multiplication () {
    while(loop) {
        a += b;
        b = 0;
        // wait(1000);
        cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    }
}

int main () {
   loop = true;
   thread myThread(multiplication);
   while(b != -1) {
       cin >> b;
   }
   loop = false;
   cout << "done!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that this program has undefined behavior: an object which is written in one thread and accessed (i.e., read or written) in another thread without synchronization creates a data race. Every data race results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok good you mentioned, but I hope @user3670601 can say if he wants to go in this direction and maybe finish the code.

Comment: nvm, it is something I may be looking for

Comment: Thanks martijnn2008, this is exactly what I needed ;) Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard library doesn't define a non-blocking read function. You could create a reader thread which blocks on read and sets a properly synchronized variable which is read from another doing computations. I'd not pursue this direction, though.

Instead, I would set up `std::cin` to be non-blocking using some platform specific settings. On UNIX, you'd use `fcntl()` to put the standard input stream into non-blocking input mode:

```
int flags = fcntl(0, F_GETFL);
fcntl(0, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

unsigned long count(0);
for (char value(0); !(std::cin >> value) || value != '1'; ) {
    std::cin.clear();
    ++count;
}
std::cout << count << '\n';
```